# View Spotfire Visualizations online

Tags: spotfire

I've created the required Visualization in dxp file. I wanted to have this file viewable using a web address so that it's accessible for everyone who doesn't have a Spotfire installed in their machine.

Any help in this aspect should be fine.

Comment: You haven't tried web player? Also, the dxp file should be saved in a library folder on the server. Then you can share web player url with users.

Comment: The organization policy might not permit us installing Web player. Is there a way where we can upload the dxp file into the spotfire server and having it viewed through a URL

Comment: Please go through the TIBCO Spotfire documentation. That will help answer your questions. https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.7.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-9D58869E-0C64-4057-A2E9-FE0353FF49B5.html

Answer (score 1):

Spotfire has a free trial at https://spotfire.tibco.com/trial

from the site:

> Experience the full capability of Spotfire on the desktop or in the
>   browser with a 30-day free trial
>
> - Access your data library from the desktop or via the browser
> - Build dashboards and analytics applications and visually explore your data
> - Easily mashup data from multiple sources Share privately with your    group or publish to the Internet

this will set you up with a Spotfire Butt account which I believe is accessible to the outside world.

---

*edit*: I see now you're already a customer. Web Player is the only way to display an analysis in the web browser. uploading it to a Cloud account could be a good solution for you, especially since you will not have to install any software locally. you'll need to reach out to the TIBCO sales department to get pricing on that. pricing is variable based on the number of users/servers/licenses/position of the moon, but I believe there's also a variable pricing option (based on your usage) if you're hosting on AWS. Sales can provide more and better info.